# If input box value is empty don't pass to database. Razor / Webmatrix

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, webmatrix

So i got a form with some questions, and i want that if an input box is empty the value do not pass to database.

How can i achieve that with razor/webmatrix ?

```
var questionOne = Request.Form["QuestionOne"];
var questionTwo = Request.Form["QuestionTwo"];
var questionThree = Request.Form["QuestionThree"];

if (IsPost && Validation.IsValid()) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
       // Execute to Database
}
}
```

Comment: why not using the MVC model validation feature with validation attributes in your viewmodel ?

Comment: Indeed, if it needs a value, then mark it with `[Required]`.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to pass null to the database instead? And can you confirm that you are using MVC? WebMatrix doesn't support MVC development so at least one of your tags is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

By implementing simple code:

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(questionOne) == false)
{
   //Put it into the database
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check this by using an attribute that does not allow an empty value for the string

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression("^(?!\s*$).+", ErrorMessage = "it mast not be empty!")]
public string questionOne { get; set; }
```